# Default selection in Media List in APEX oracle

Tags: oracle, apex

I'm using APEX oracle ver 23.1
I have two regions for two different classic reports in the same page.

In the first classic report, I used table 1 including column ID and name. The Appearance in Attribute tab is set to Media List. Then when I click on one value in classic report, it will generate a link in which value of column ID is assigned to an item P1_value.

In the second classic report, I applied a SQL query using value of P1_value in where condition on table 2. Table 2 includes columns ID_table2 which is referenced to column ID in table 1.

When I open this page for the first time, I observed that no selection was done in classic report 1, and hence no data found in classic report 2.

I'd like to setup such that in classic report 1, the largest value of ID is always selected by default. And hence classic report 2 always displays records when ID_table2 = P1_value.

May I ask what I should implement to achieve above behavior.

Thanks in advance for your support.